# Create second or next <li> under default <li> after reload page | jQuery, LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to create LocalStorage data for My Folder Creation .

**HTML :**

> This is my default `li`. I call it *All audience* folder's

```
<!-- Result goes here -->
<ul class="nav">

  <li>
    <div class="zf-folder" style="width: 232px;">
      <div class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 50px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">
        <div class="_sideFolder"></div>
        <div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">
          <div class="ellipsis">
            <div class="_1i5w">
              <div class="_icon-col">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#mainFolder" data-toggle="tab" style="text-decoration: none;">All Audiences<span class="hyperspan" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0;"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

**jQuery :**

```
var count = 1;
$(".submitButton").click(function() {
let label = count++;
// make a function that returns the DOM with updated count
function getNewList(foldername) {

  var addFolder = '<li>' +
    '<div class="zf-folder" style="width: 232px;">' +
    '<div class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 50px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">' +
    '<div class="_sideFolder"></div>' +
    '<div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">' +
    '<div class="ellipsis">' +
    '<div class="_iconFolder">' +
    '<div class="_icon-col">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<a href="#folder' + label +
    '" data-toggle="tab" style="text-decoration: none;">' +
    foldername + '<span class="hyperspan" style="width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0;"></span></a>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>';
  return addFolder;
}

  var inputan = $("#input_nameFolder").val();

  // update the result array
  var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("folderList"));

  if (result == null) {
    result = [];
  }

  let newfolderHTML = getNewList(inputan);

  result.push({
    folder: newfolderHTML
  });



     // save the new result array
      localStorage.setItem("folderList", JSON.stringify(result));

      // append the new li
      $(".nav").append(newfolderHTML); // i want include myDiv

      //clear input 
      $("#input_nameFolder").val('');
    });

    // on init fill the ul
    var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("folderList"));
    if (result != null) {


//get the nav reference in DOM
  let nav = $(".nav");

  //clear the html contents
  nav.html('');

  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var item = result[i];
    $(".nav").append(item.folder);
  }
}
```

> How to  adding **new `<li>`** tag under my default li (all audience)
>   after *reload page*/*click run* jsfiddle when user input a new value?

You can see after adding an input and reload web / jsfiddle, *new input* folder's (second `li`) overwrite *all audience* (first `li`).

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0hrL919/3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to save the initial element upon initialization, see:

```
// on init fill the ul
var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("folderList"));
if (result != null) {
    //get the nav reference in DOM
    let nav = $(".nav");

    //clear the html contents
    nav.html('');

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        var item = result[i];
        $(".nav").append(item.folder);
    }
} else {
    //Save the "All Audiences" content upon empty folderList
    let initialElement = [];
    initialElement.push({
        folder: $('ul.nav').html()
    });
    localStorage.setItem("folderList", JSON.stringify(initialElement));
}
```

See: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taeprn5o/2/)

Comment: You save my life !!

Comment: While your are working on it: Add some code to at least check if folderList has valid data in it. You are trusting the client to deliver data to your application, possibly with added functionaility for the entries in folderList. If folderList gets corrupted or manipulated, strange things may ensue.

Comment: I'm working on a problem in the folder click function.
page reloading when the folder is clicked.